# count the row and total its value in array php

Tags: php, arrays

Im having a badtime solving this problem. Already tried [`array_count_values`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) but it aint work.

This is my code

```
$json = '[
            { "MONTH": "Jan", "ROOM": "Rizal", "ID": "112551", "BALANCE": "5",  "TAGGED_ID": "112551" },
            { "MONTH": "Jan", "ROOM": "Rizal", "ID": "112551", "BALANCE": "10", "TAGGED_ID": null },
            { "MONTH": "Jan", "ROOM": "Luna",  "ID": "112551", "BALANCE": "20", "TAGGED_ID": null },
            { "MONTH": "Feb", "ROOM": "Rizal", "ID": "112551", "BALANCE": "5",  "TAGGED_ID": "112551" }
        ]';
```

In this array, i want to count the row for all the month of `Jan` and room of `Rizal` & `Luna` and then add this count as additional key in the array.

Expected output

```
$json = '[
            { "MONTH": "Jan", "ROOM": "Rizal", "ID": "112551", "BALANCE": "5",  "TAGGED_ID": "112551",  "ROW_COUNT": "2"},
            { "MONTH": "Jan", "ROOM": "Rizal", "ID": "112551", "BALANCE": "10", "TAGGED_ID": null,      "ROW_COUNT": "2" },
            { "MONTH": "Jan", "ROOM": "Luna",  "ID": "112551", "BALANCE": "20", "TAGGED_ID": null,      "ROW_COUNT": "1" },
            { "MONTH": "Feb", "ROOM": "Rizal", "ID": "112551", "BALANCE": "5",  "TAGGED_ID": "112551" , "ROW_COUNT": "1" }
        ]';
```

As you can see, i have added `ROW_COUNT` column in the expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes it's just easiest to iterate over the data. Note that in the second iteration we pass a reference so we can modify the value.

```
$data = json_decode($json, true);
foreach ($data as $value) {
    $counts[$value['MONTH']][$value['ROOM']] = ($counts[$value['MONTH']][$value['ROOM']] ?? 0) + 1;
}
foreach ($data as &$value) {
    $value['ROW_COUNT'] = $counts[$value['MONTH']][$value['ROOM']];
}
$json = json_encode($data);
echo $json;
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "MONTH": "Jan",
        "ROOM": "Rizal",
        "ID": "112551",
        "BALANCE": "5",
        "TAGGED_ID": "112551",
        "ROW_COUNT": 2
    },
    {
        "MONTH": "Jan",
        "ROOM": "Rizal",
        "ID": "112551",
        "BALANCE": "10",
        "TAGGED_ID": null,
        "ROW_COUNT": 2
    },
    {
        "MONTH": "Jan",
        "ROOM": "Luna",
        "ID": "112551",
        "BALANCE": "20",
        "TAGGED_ID": null,
        "ROW_COUNT": 1
    },
    {
        "MONTH": "Feb",
        "ROOM": "Rizal",
        "ID": "112551",
        "BALANCE": "5",
        "TAGGED_ID": "112551",
        "ROW_COUNT": 1
    }
]
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/jGmPO)

Note that if this data is coming from a database, it may well be easier to get this result directly from your query.

Comment: Hi @nick, thanks for the info btw. Im not using this way anymore since i think it will slowed my function unlike your suggestion to manipulate this on query. upon working on query i noticed that this is more faster than manipulating to code. Thanks!

Comment: @MONSTEEEER no worries - I'm glad you've got a good solution out of asking the question; and this could still be useful to others who can't modify their query.